# Passing char matrix to C function

Tags: c, visual-c++, matrix

I have to work with a given function that is declared like this:

```
void someFunc (char** characters, int from, int to);
```

The problem is, i cant find a way to pass a matrix to it, for example:

```
char matrix[4][4] = { { 'a', 'e' , 'i', 'm'}, 
                      { 'b', 'f' , 'j', 'n'},  
                      { 'c', 'g' , 'k', 'p'},  
                      { 'd', 'h' , 'l', 's'} };
    someFunc(matrix, 2, 3);   //doesnt work
    someFunc(&matrix, 2, 3);  //doesnt work
```

The compiler complains, but i cant change the signature of someFunc, so how i can do to pass a char matrix to the function?

Comment: What does `someFunc` expect, exactly? An array of `char*` pointers, each pointing to an array of characters? `matrix` is not laid out this way.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Yes, it is an array of char* pointers. I tought it was the same.

Comment: No. `matrix` is just a block of 16 chars; there are no pointers. You could do something like this: `char* characters[] = {matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], matrix[3]}; someFunc(characters, ...);`

Comment: Well the problem is that you are passing in a fixed length array of [4][4] whereas the function is expecting a pointer to a pointer. You could change your function to accept a fixed length array. i.e. void someFunc (char characters[4][4], int from, int to); or if your matrix is of variable length on the heap void someFunc (char characters[][], int from, int to);

Comment: @ScottyBauer, that definitely won't work.

Comment: @CarlNorum, that is correct, we went over it in one of the answers below.

Comment: @Igor - Can you (or anyone else) explain: I understand your comment that `char *matrix[4][4]...` is a block of 16 characters, but can it not also be referred to as a set of char pointers to 4 strings?

Comment: @ryyker: think about it this way. An array of four char* pointers would occupy `4*sizeof(char*) == 16` or perhaps 32 bytes. `matrix` certainly doesn't have extra 16 bytes set aside to store those pointers, in addition to actual characters. You can, of course, separately allocate an array of four pointers and initialize it so that each one points to a row in the matrix - which is what I've shown.

Answer (score 2):

AS @IgorTandetnik said

define like this

```
char* data[]= {matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], matrix[3]};
someFunc(data, 2, 3);   // works fine
```

**array of character pointers initialized with the each row of matrix and then passed this as argument**

test code:

```
   #include<stdio.h>
   void someFunc (char** characters, int from, int to);

    char matrix[4][4] = { { 'a', 'e' , 'i', 'm'},
                  { 'b', 'f' , 'j', 'n'},
                  { 'c', 'g' , 'k', 'p'},
              { 'd', 'h' , 'l', 's'} };
   main()
   {


  char* data[]= {matrix[0], matrix[1], matrix[2], matrix[3]};
  someFunc(data, 2, 3);   
   }

    void someFunc (char** c , int from, int to)
   {

  int i=0,j=0;

  for(i=0;i<4;i++) 
  for(j=0;j<4;j++)
  printf("%c\n",c[i][j]); //printf("%c",*(c[i]+j));

  }
```

Comment: Well, it "works" in the sense that you can get it to compile. But if you try to actually use `characters` pointer inside `someFunc`, the program will crash.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik Can you explain better why is that?, the "matrix" definition is not correct to be used here?

Comment: @IgorTandetnik What do you mean Use? I don't think you're right but I am looking forward to be told otherwise.

Comment: `someFunc` expects a parameter of a certain type. `matrix` has a different type. You can't call `someFunc(matrix)` for the same reason you can't call `someFunc(42)`. You can, of course, silence the compiler with `someFunc((char**)42)`, but the call is still nonsense.

Comment: @Scotty Bauer: "use" as in "do something with". E.g. `printf("%c", characters[0][0]);`. Try it, see how well it works out for you.

Comment: @IgorTandetnik ,Edited My answer.array of charcter pointers initialized with the each row of matrix and then passed this as argument. thanks

Answer (score 2):

instead of using an automatic matrix just malloc a pointer to pointer the code goes like this

```
main(void)
{
    int i;
    char **ptr = NULL;
    ptr = (char**)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);
    for(i = 0 ; i < 4 ; i++)
         ptr[i] = (char*)malloc(sizeof(char) * 4);

    //initialize your matrix here 
    someFunc(ptr , 2 , 3); 
}
```

or , if you are ready to modify the function prototype (just a tiny bit) use this one instead `void sumFunc(char matrix[][4) , int from , int to)` and you won't have to change any thing else

Answer (score 1):

An example of char **variable would be:

```
char  *array[]={"this","is","char","pointer"};
```

Used like:

```
someFunc(array, 2, 3);
```

An example of an array of the previous would have to be something like:

```
char *array[][5] = { 
{"this","is","char","element","one"},  
{"this","is","char","element","two"},  
{"this","is","char","element","three"}};
```

But that is not what your prototype requires.  Use the previous example to see that that does for you.

[EDIT] per your question and my comment, here is how to access the content of an array.  (it is random and can be printed in any format you need).

```
    #include <windows.h>
#include <ansi_c.h>

int main(void)
{
    char *array[]={"this","is","char","pointer"};
    int i,j;

    //print in columns
    printf("Columns:\n");
    for(i=0;i<7; i++)
    {

        for(j=0;j<4;j++)
        {
            if(i> strlen(array[j])) 
                printf(" ");
                else
                printf("%c", array[j][i]);  
        }
        printf("\n");
    }
    //print in rows (easier)
    printf("\n\nRows:\n");
    for(i=0;i<4;i++)
    {
        printf("%s\n", array[i]);   
    }
    getchar();
    return 0;   
}
```

Comment: @Wyvern666 - It would be great to have a little idea how the arguments are used in the prototype you have to use.  That might result in more useful answers.

Comment: Its like a matrix of strings, where every column should be a string. In your suggestion, the words are in files if i am correct.

Comment: Hmmm. Still not sure how the function someFunc(...) is supposed to work. In my example above, the array is defined to contain the four strings _this, is, char_ and _pointer_. It is arbitrary how you can access that data,  See my edit above for example.

Answer (score 1):

The below code will work. But you may need to access the array using one index instead of two index in the function. When you declare a double index array, the data is not store as a "pointer to pointer". So you may not pass *char foo0[ ][ ]* using *char **foo1*.

```
void someFunc (char* characters)
{
    char c = character[0]; // c = 'a'
    c = character[4]       // c = 'b'
    c = character[8]       // c = 'c'
    c = character[12]      // c = 'd'
}


void main(void)
{
    char matrix[4][4] = { 
    { 'a', 'e' , 'i', 'm'}, 
    { 'b', 'f' , 'j', 'n'},  
    { 'c', 'g' , 'k', 'p'},  
    { 'd', 'h' , 'l', 's'} };

    someFunc((char*)matrix);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I had a similar experience once and I found out that using char matrixes kinda give some issues ... this is my actual suggestion, I hope you'll understand it. (I know it's late, but maybe it will be to aid for somebody else)

```
void someFunc(char* matrix, int from, int to){/*function declaration*/}


int main(){
int x = 4; //first matrix's dimension
int y = 4; //second matrix's dimension
char matrix[x*y];
//printing the matrix all in a single row
for(int i=0, i<x, i++)
   for(int j=0, j<y, j++)
      printf("%c", matrix[i+j*x]);
//it is just way simpler, reduces a ton of complexity, and having a string is much more flexible than having a matrix, especially with chars
return 0
}
```